# Combining 2 jsons objects

Tags: javascript, json

I've 2 json object that I would like to combine. I tried using `concat` and `merge` function, but the result is not what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var jason1 = 
{
  "book1": {
    "price": 10,
    "weight": 30
  },
  "book2": {
    "price": 40,
    "weight": 60
  }
};
```

and this is the other object

```
var jason2 =
{
  "book3": {
    "price": 70,
    "weight": 100
  },
  "book4": {
    "price": 110,
    "weight": 130
  }
};
```

This is what I want:

```
var jasons =
{
  "book1": {
    "price": 10,
    "weight": 30
  },
  "book2": {
    "price": 40,
    "weight": 60
  }
  "book3": {
    "price": 70,
    "weight": 100
  },
  "book4": {
    "price": 110,
    "weight": 130
  }
};
```

Comment: Those aren't JSON objects, they're just objects. JSON is a way to represent an object as a string (e.g. for transmission over the network).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the source of the `Object.extend` method from the Prototype.js framework:

https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/object.js#L88

```
function extend(destination, source) {
  for (var property in source) {
    destination[property] = source[property];
  }
}
```

The usage is then…

```
extend(jason1, jason2);
```

The object `jason1` now contains exactly what you want.

Comment: This will certainly work but i dont think its worth adding a library just for this when it can be achieved fairly easily without.

Comment: I didn't suggest to use the library, just to look at its source (the implementation of the `Object.extend` method).

Comment: Ahh i saw prototype and thought you were suggesting he add the library... my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You jsut need to manually iterate over them:

```
var both = [json1, json2],
    jasons = {};


for (var i=0; i < both.length; i++) {
  for (var k in both[i]) {
    if(both[i].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
       jasons[k] = both[i][k];
    }
  }
}
```

Heres a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc3TP/). You might want to think about what happens if there are duplicate keys though - for example what if `book3` exists in both json objects. With the code i provided the value in the second one always wins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, although I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.

```
var jason1 = {
    "book1": {
        "price": 10,
        "weight": 30
    },
    "book2": {
        "price": 40,
        "weight": 60
    }
};
var jason2 = {
    "book3": {
        "price": 70,
        "weight": 100
    },
    "book4": {
        "price": 110,
        "weight": 130
    }
};
var jasons = {};
var key;
for (key in jason1) {
    if (jason1.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(jasons.hasOwnProperty(key))) {
        jasons[key] = jason1[key];
    }
}
for (key in jason2) {
    if (jason2.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(jasons.hasOwnProperty(key))) {
        jasons[key] = jason2[key];
    }
}
console.log(jasons);
```